# How to get Data::Diver to produce arrays?

Tags: perl

The below script will output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'tank' => {
                      'fs' => {
                                'fs2b' => undef,
                                'fs2a' => undef,
                                'fs2c' => undef
                              }
                    }
        };
```

where I really wanted a hash of hash of array like this

```
$VAR1 = {
          'tank' => {
                      'fs' => [
                                'fs2a',
                                'fs2b',
                                'fs2c'
                              ]
                    }
        };
```

**Question**

How would  that be done with [`Data::Diver`](http://search.cpan.org/~tyemq/Data-Diver-1.0101/Diver.pm)?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Data::Diver 'DiveRef';

my @array = ("tank", "tank/fs", "tank/fs/fs2a", "tank/fs/fs2b", "tank/fs/fs2c");
my %hash = ();

foreach my $element (@array) {
    DiveRef( \%hash, \( split /\//, $element ) );
}

print Dumper \%hash;
```

*(Code provided by [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27607990) to another question.)*

**Update**

The array in the code is just an example. The real array have ~100 elements, so the solution can't be hard coded.

Comment: Is the data structure always going to be a HoHoA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DiveVal(\%data, 'tank', 'fs', 0) = 'fs2a';
DiveVal(\%data, 'tank', 'fs', 1) = 'fs2b';
DiveVal(\%data, 'tank', 'fs', 2) = 'fs2c';
```

or

```
push @{ DiveVal(\%data, 'tank', 'fs') }, 'fs2a';
push @{ DiveVal(\%data, 'tank', 'fs') }, 'fs2b';
push @{ DiveVal(\%data, 'tank', 'fs') }, 'fs2c';
```

To get the desired data structure from `"tank", "tank/fs", "tank/fs/fs2a", "tank/fs/fs2b", "tank/fs/fs2c"`, extra information is needed. For you example, you could have the understanding that the data structure is always going to be a HoHoA.

```
my @data = ("tank", "tank/fs", "tank/fs/fs2a", "tank/fs/fs2b", "tank/fs/fs2c");
my %data;
for (@data) {
   my @parts = split qr{/};
   if (@parts < 3) {
       DiveVal(\%data, map \$_, @parts);
   } else {
       my $val = pop(@parts);
       push @{ DiveVal(\%data, map \$_, @parts) }, $val; 
   }
}
```

But which such a limited structure, there's no reason to use Data::Diver. It would be far faster to avoid it.

```
my @data = ("tank", "tank/fs", "tank/fs/fs2a", "tank/fs/fs2b", "tank/fs/fs2c");
my %data;
for (@data) {
   my @parts = split qr{/};
   if    (@parts == 1) { \( $data{$parts[0]}            ); }
   elsif (@parts == 2) { \( $data{$parts[0]}{$parts[1]} ); }
   else { push @{ $data{$parts[0]}{$parts[1]} }, $parts[2]; }
}
```

You might even be able to use

```
my @data = ("tank", "tank/fs", "tank/fs/fs2a", "tank/fs/fs2b", "tank/fs/fs2c");
my %data;
for (@data) {
   my @parts = split qr{/};
   push @{ $data{$parts[0]}{$parts[1]} }, $parts[2] if @parts == 3;
}
```

Comment: The last one is awesome! The second to last gives me a `Useless use of push` error and a syntax error at the `if` line.

Comment: Fixed various bugs. That last one assumes that items with only one or two parts are superfluous (i.e. will eventually be followed by one with three parts).